# Changing item value of list not reflected when using copy() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I recently came across some code that makes use of redefining a value of a list as well as copying a list using the copy() function, as shown below:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = list1.copy()

list1[2] = 10

print(list1); print(list2)
```

I thought that the two printed lists list1 and list2 would be identical and have the index 2 changed to the value of 10, as list2 is a copy of list1. However, list2 doesn't reflect the change made to list1.

Would anyone have an idea as to why this happens? Thank you :)

Comment: That's the whole point of making a copy, so that changes to one *don't* affect the other.

Comment: You would get the result you expect if you wrote `list2 = list1`

Comment: Do `list2 = list1` not `list2 = list1.copy()`. The copy is somewhat equivalent to `list2 = [i for i in list1]` or `list2 = list(list1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually what `copy` does. If you had not used `copy` and simply set `list2 = list2` it means that both `list1` and `list2` point to the very same memory address. For that reason, if you change anything in `list1`, it will be reflected in `list2` and vice-versa.

However, when running `list2 = list1.copy()`, a new variable is created in memory and is pointed by `list2`, which means `list1` and `list2` originally have the same values but are actually two different instances since they point two different memory adresses. This is the reason why, if you change anything on `list1`, it will not get reflected in `list2` as they are totally different and independent objects.

Nevertheless, be aware that `copy` is a shallow copy (opposite of deep copy), which means that any object in the list will not be copied too. Only first level elements are copied. In practise it means :

```py
list1 = [1, 'a', "string", [2, 'b', 8], 'c']
list2 = list1.copy()

list2[0] = 0   # Will only affect list2
list1[3][2] = 12  # Will affect both as inner list was not copied

print(list1)
[1, 'a', "string", [2, 'b', 12], 'c']
print(list2)
[0, 'a', "string", [2, 'b', 12], 'c']
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! 

If I were to use the append() or insert() functions to add a new element to list1, would the added element also not be reflected wen I use the copy() function?

Comment: Absolutely ! As both list are different objects in memory, adding to one does not add to the other

Comment: If this has answered your question, do not hesitate to check it so that other users can find it too and answer their question.

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the documentation for `list.copy()`, you see that it makes a shallow copy. So, the object itself will indeed be a new object, but any references it contains will be copied.

So:

```
list1 = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3, 4]
list2 = list1.copy()
list1[2][2] = 'x'
```

will indeed modify both; since it really modifies the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`, and both copies have a reference to that same one.

What you wanted to do only works if you let `list2 = list1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you do that, you will copy and somewhat create a new list. If you assigned your list directly that wouldn't happen, see the code below:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list2 = list1

list1[2] = 10

assert list1 == list2
```

This means that updating `list1` would result in an update for `list2`. But, the `.copy()` method does the contrary and no update would happen in the new list.